# error while installing apache

Tags: server, software-installation, apache2, apache2.4

I am getting error while processing `make install`.
My code is as follows:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/httpd.git
cd httpd
svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr && cd srclib/apr && ./buildconf && ./build libtool && make && make install
./buildconf && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
echo "ServerName localhost" >> /usr/local/conf/httpd.conf
```

Error is as follow :

```
...
Building shared: mod_mime.la
make[4]: Entering directory '/httpd/modules/http'
/usr/local/apr/build-2/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread      -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE     -I. -I/httpd/os/unix -I/httpd/include -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-2 -I/httpd/modules/aaa -I/httpd/modules/cache -I/httpd/modules/core -I/httpd/modules/database -I/httpd/modules/filters -I/httpd/modules/ldap -I/httpd/modules/loggers -I/httpd/modules/lua -I/httpd/modules/proxy -I/httpd/modules/session -I/httpd/modules/ssl -I/httpd/modules/test -I/httpd/server -I/httpd/modules/arch/unix -I/httpd/modules/dav/main -I/httpd/modules/generators -I/httpd/modules/mappers -prefer-pic -c mod_mime.c && touch mod_mime.slo
/usr/local/apr/build-2/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread           -o mod_mime.la -rpath /usr/local/modules -module -avoid-version  mod_mime.lo
make[4]: Leaving directory '/httpd/modules/http'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/httpd/modules/http'
make[3]: Entering directory '/httpd/modules/http2'
Building shared: mod_http2.la
make[4]: Entering directory '/httpd/modules/http2'
/usr/local/apr/build-2/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread      -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE     -I. -I/httpd/os/unix -I/httpd/include -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-2 -I/httpd/modules/aaa -I/httpd/modules/cache -I/httpd/modules/core -I/httpd/modules/database -I/httpd/modules/filters -I/httpd/modules/ldap -I/httpd/modules/loggers -I/httpd/modules/lua -I/httpd/modules/proxy -I/httpd/modules/session -I/httpd/modules/ssl -I/httpd/modules/test -I/httpd/server -I/httpd/modules/arch/unix -I/httpd/modules/dav/main -I/httpd/modules/generators -I/httpd/modules/mappers -prefer-pic -c mod_h2.c && touch mod_h2.slo
mod_h2.c:25:29: fatal error: nghttp2/nghttp2.h: No such file or directory
 #include <nghttp2/nghttp2.h>
                             ^
compilation terminated.
/httpd/build/rules.mk:213: recipe for target 'mod_h2.slo' failed
make[4]: *** [mod_h2.slo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/httpd/modules/http2'
/httpd/build/rules.mk:117: recipe for target 'shared-build-recursive' failed
make[3]: Leaving directory '/httpd/modules/http2'
/httpd/build/rules.mk:117: recipe for target 'shared-build-recursive' failed
make[2]: Leaving directory '/httpd/modules'
make[2]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
/httpd/build/rules.mk:117: recipe for target 'shared-build-recursive' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/httpd'
make[1]: *** [shared-build-recursive] Error 1
/httpd/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Please provide me the solution

Comment: Rollback. Why? After your edit it's a completely different question.

Answer (score 1):

The part

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/apache/httpd.git
> cd httpd
> svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr && cd srclib/apr && ./buildconf && ./build libtool && make && make install
> ./buildconf && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local && make && make install
> echo "ServerName localhost" >> /usr/local/conf/httpd.conf
> ```

is pretty confusing. But because of the error message:

Install the missing libraries via

```
sudo apt-get install libnghttp2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
```

And you have to use

```
sudo make install
```

instead of

```
make install
```

at the end of your command queue. Otherwise you will probably get immediately the next error.

Comment: still getting error as follow

Comment: checking Expat 1.0/1.1... no
  setting LDFLAGS to "-L/usr/local/lib"
  setting INCLUDES to "-I/usr/local/include"
checking Expat 1.95.x in /usr/local... no
  nulling LDFLAGS
  nulling INCLUDES
  setting APRUTIL_EXPORT_LIBS to ""
configure: error: No XML parser found!  Please specify --with-expat or --with-libxml2
time="2015-09-24T18:57:58+05:30" level=info msg="The command [/bin/sh -c svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk srclib/apr && cd srclib/apr && ./buildconf && ./configure && make && make install] returned a non-zero code: 1"

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Comment: But already you realize that this is a new problem?

Comment: A    srclib/apr/configure.in
 U   srclib/apr
Checked out revision 1705062.
buildconf: checking installation...
buildconf: python not found.
           You need python installed
           to build APR from SVN.

Comment: The third answer: `sudo apt-get install python`

Comment: still getting same error for ubuntu:15.04

Comment: @Ravi_SS: you cannot keep on asking questions in the comments, please edit your original question and remove all these comments or just [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) for well... every new question you have!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error:  "/httpd/build/rules.mk:75: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed" is because you're missing the development libraries for Apache2.

Do this: sudo apt install apache2-dev -y
         ; sudo make
         ; sudo make install