# Error while installing haskell

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh, git, haskell

i am installing haskell code is as follow

```
git clone git://github.com/ghc/ghc.git && cd ghc && ./sync-all get
cd ghc && ./sync-all get cd ghc && ./boot && ./configure && make && make install
```

when i try with ./sync-all get i get following error:

```
Cloning into 'ghc'...
/bin/sh: 1: ./sync-all: not found
```

when i try without ./sync-all in code i get following error

```
    It seems you cloned this repository from GitHub. But your git config files
don't contain the url rewrites that are needed to make this work (GitHub
doesn't support '/' in repository names, so we use a different naming scheme
for the submodule repositories there).

Please run the following commands first:

  git config --global url."git://github.com/ghc/packages-".insteadOf     git://github.com/ghc/packages/
  git config --global url."http://github.com/ghc/packages-".insteadOf    http://github.com/ghc/packages/
  git config --global url."https://github.com/ghc/packages-".insteadOf   https://github.com/ghc/packages/
  git config --global url."ssh://git@github.com/ghc/packages-".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/ghc/packages/
  git config --global url."git@github.com:/ghc/packages-".insteadOf      git@github.com:/ghc/packages/

And then:

  git submodule update --init
  ./boot

Or start over, and clone the GHC repository from the haskell server:

  git clone --recursive git://git.haskell.org/ghc.git

For more information, see:
  * https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Newcomers or
  * https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building/GettingTheSources#CloningfromGitHub
```

please provide me the solution

Comment: How many things you compile at the same time? Your question regarding Apache is answered. http://askubuntu.com/q/677883/367165

Comment: i have many vm running having ubuntu:15.04 vivid

Comment: **[Edit]**  your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy ghc-7.10.3`

Comment: Sorry, apt-cache, changed my comment

Comment: test@pts00449-vm4:~$ apt-cache policy ghc-7.10.3
N: Unable to locate package ghc-7.10.3
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ghc-7.10.3'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29531/discussion-between-a-b-and-ravi-ss).

Comment: The [haskell plaform is in the Ubuntu repo?](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=haskell-platform)

Comment: The need is haskell compiler not the the haskell platform

Answer (score 2):

The [Haskell Platform](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/haskell-platform) is available via the Ubuntu repository's.

**Haskell Platform**

To install via repo, just do like so:

- `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`

Install via [website](https://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html#linux-generic):

- `wget https://haskell.org/platform/download/7.10.2/haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.gz`
- `tar xf haskell-platform-7.10.2-a-unknown-linux-deb7.tar.gz`
- `sudo ./install-haskell-platform.sh`

**Haskell Compiler**

To install the Haskell Compiler, follow the steps one by one.

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common`
- `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:hvr/ghc`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install -y cabal-install-1.20 ghc-7.8.4`

> ```
> cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
> export PATH="\$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.20/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.4/bin:\$PATH"
> EOF
> export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.20/bin:/opt/ghc/7.8.4/bin:$PATH
> ```

- `cabal update`
- `cabal install alex happy`

Comment: You're right, it works =)

Comment: i need haskel compiler not the haskell platform. As you can check git://github.com/ghc/ghc.git repo

Comment: @Ravi_SS  I updated my answer on how to install the Haskell Compiler!

Comment: @blade19899 apt-get install ghc-7.8.4. This command is giving an error Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ghc-7.8.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ghc-7.8.4'

Comment: @Ravi_SS I had a similar error for the cabal package.  I did `apt-cache search ghc-` to find the available ones (and `apt-cache search cabal` for checking cabal versions).

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [README](https://github.com/ghc/ghc), clone the repository via

```
git clone --recursive git://git.haskell.org/ghc.git
```

After that

```
cd ghc
./boot
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

The Problem

```
$ ./configure             
checking for gfind... no
checking for find... /usr/bin/find
checking for sort... /usr/bin/sort
checking for GHC version date... inferred 7.11.20150924
checking for GHC Git commit id... inferred 1395185f56cda4774d27ae419b10f570276b674d
checking for ghc... /usr/bin/ghc
checking version of ghc... 7.6.3
configure: error: GHC version 7.8 or later is required to compile GHC.
```

Therefore for (`amd64` and `i386`)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ghc-7.10.3
```

But this piece of ... is installed in `/opt` therefore you have to create some symbolic links or you have to adjust a few paths.

Comment: apt-get install dialog - fine
apt-get install software-properties-common - fine apt-get install ghc-7.10.3 - Error as follow
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ghc-7.10.3
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ghc-7.10.3'

Comment: You forgot `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:hvr/ghc; sudo apt-get update`

Comment: above mentioned steps are done with apt-get install dialog

Comment: And you ask again new questions in the comments. Your question is: *How do I install software from a PPA?*

Comment: i see no heskell installed.

Comment: Above given solution didn't worked